# Can anyone explain the family tree of Pandavas?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas

We are aware of Draupadi as the wife of Pandavas whereas Subhadra is the wife of Arjuna and, [Hidimbi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidimbi) is the wife of Bhima.

Besides Draupadi, are there any other wives of Yudhisthir, Nakul and Sahdev?

Similarly, Pandava children, Abhimanyu, son of Arjuna-Subhadra and, Ghatotkacha, son of Bhima-Hidimbi are well-known.

What are the names of Draupadi's sons and other Pandava children, if they exist?

Comment: is your question about wife's name or names of draupadi's son?

Comment: It's about both.. Wife's name of yudhisthira, nakul, sahdeva and son of daraupadi and other wives if exist..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Name of sons of Draupadi are

> - Prativindhya from Yudhishthira
> - Sutasoma from Bheema
> - Srutakirti from Arjuna
> - Satanika from Nakul
> - Srutakarma from Sahadev
>
> Reference : [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draupadi)

Yudhisthira, Nakula and Sahadeva also had a wife other than Draupadi

> Yudhisthira had other wife Devika, the daughter of Govasana of the
> Saivya tribe, who bore him a son named Yaudheya.
>
> Refer : [Yudhisthira](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yudhisthira)
>
> Nakula had other wife Karenumati, the daughter of the king of the
> Chedi Kingdom, who bore him a son, Niramitra.
>
> Refer : [Nakul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakula#Marriage)
>
> Sahadeva married his maternal cousin Vijaya, the daughter of Dyutimat,
> the king of Madra, and had a son named Suhotra.
>
> Refer : [Sahadeva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahadeva#Marriage)

Comment: Like Sahadeva & Vijaya, Arjuna & Subhadra were also first cousins.

Answer (score 20):

[Here](http://www.srimadbhagavatam.org/familytree.html) is the family tree of the Pandavas:
[image]

As you can see, Arjuna had four wives, each of whom bore him a son: Draupadi had Shrutakirti, Krishna's sister Subhadra had Abhimanyu, the Naga princess Ulupi had Iravan, and Chitrangada princess of Manipura had Babruvahana.  And each of Arjuna's four brothers also had a son with Draupadi: Yudishtra had Prativindhya, Bhima had Sutasoma, Nakula had Shatatija, and Sahadeva had Shrutakarma.  And although the family tree doesn't show it, Bhima and the Rakshasi Hidimbi had Ghatotkacha. In addition, Yudishtra and Devika had Yaudheya, Bhima and Valandhara had Sarvaga, Nakula and Karenumati had Niramitra, and Sahadeva and Vijaya had Suhotra.

Now Abhimanyu, Iravan, and Ghatotkacha all died during the Mahabharata war.  And the five sons of Draupadi were killed immediately after the war by Ashwattama, who thought they were the five Pandavas; he was trying to avenge the death of his father Drona.  (For this he was cursed with a painful immortality.)  In any case, Babruvahana was the only child of Arjuna to live after the Mahabharata war; he became the king of his mother's kingdom of Manipura.  And when the Pandavas went to the Himalayas after the death of Krishna, they left the kingdom of Hastinapura to Abhimanyu's son Parikshit, the first Kali Yuga ruler of the Kuru dynasty.

Answer (score 2):

When Drapadi married to five Pandava's they all had given her a word that they will not marry any other girl their whole life.

Bhima married to Hidamba before getting marry with Draupadi, because she was in love with Bhima. She told mother Kunti that either she will do suicide or allow her to get marry with Bhima. Mother kunti told her that she can marry to Bhima but as she belongs to Rakshasas family. However she would not be  allowed to enter in to Hastinapur's kingdom.

Arjuna & Subhdra were in love with each other. Lord Krishna helped them to get marry. For Lord Krishna , Draupadi like his sister, and hence Draupadi allowed Subhdra to stay with them.

From the [Wikipedia source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upapandavas),

Drapadi's sons name are as follows,

> - Prativindha : Prativindha or Shrutavindha was born to Yudhisthira and Draupadi and was the eldest of the Upapandavas
> - Satanika : Satanika was born to Nakula and Draupadi.
> - Sutasoma : Sutasoma was the son of Bhima and Draupadi was the third of the Upapandavas.
> - Srutasena : Srutasena was born to Sahadeva and Draupadi and the fourth upapandava.
> - Srutakarma : rutakarma was the son born to Arjuna and Draupadi, the youngest Upapandavas.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01096.htm

> "Daksha begat Aditi, and Aditi begat Vivaswat, and Vivaswat begat Manu, and Manu begat Ha and Ha begat Pururavas. And Pururavas begat Ayus, and Ayus begat Nahusha, and Nahusha begat Yayati. And Yayati had two wives, viz., Devayani, the daughter of Usanas, and Sarmishtha the daughter of Vrishaparvan. Here occurs a sloka regarding (Yayati's) descendants, 'Devayani gave birth to Yadu and Turvasu; and Vrishaparvan's daughter, Sarmishtha gave birth to Druhyu, Anu, and Puru., And the descendants of Yadu are the Yadavas and of Puru are the Pauravas. And Puru had a wife of the name of Kausalya, on whom he begat a son named Janamejaya who performed three horse-sacrifices and a sacrifice called Viswajit. And then he entered into the woods. And Janamejaya had married Ananta, the daughter of Madhava, and begat upon her a son called Prachinwat. And the prince was so called because he had conquered all the eastern countries up to the very confines of the region where the Sun rises. And Prachinwat married Asmaki, a daughter of the Yadavas and begat upon her a son named Sanyati. And Sanyati married Varangi, the daughter of Drishadwata and begat upon her a son named Ahayanti. And Ahayanti married Bhanumati, the daughter of Kritavirya and begat upon her a son named Sarvabhauma. And Sarvabhauma married Sunanda, the daughter of the Kekaya prince, having obtained her by force. And
>
> he begat upon her a son named Jayatsena, who married Susrava, the daughter of the Vidarbha king and begat upon her Avachina, And Avachina also married another princess of Vidarbha, Maryada by name. And he begat on her a son named Arihan. And Arihan married Angi and begat on her Mahabhauma. And Mahabhauma married Suyajna, the daughter of Prasenajit. And of her was born Ayutanayi. And he was so called because he had performed a sacrifice at which the fat of an Ayuta (ten thousands) of male beings was required. And Ayutanayi took for a wife Kama, the daughter of Prithusravas. And by her was born a son named Akrodhana, who took to wife Karambha, the daughter of the king of Kalinga. And of her was born Devatithi, and Devatithi took for his wife Maryada, the princess of Videha. And of her was born a son named Arihan. And Arihan took to wife Sudeva, the princess of Anga, and upon her he begat a son named Riksha. And Riksha married Jwala, the daughter of Takshaka, and he begat upon her a son of the name of Matinara, who performed on the bank of Saraswati the twelve years' sacrifice said to be so efficacious. On conclusion of the sacrifice, Saraswati appeared in person before the king and chose him for husband. And he begat upon her a son named Tansu. Here occurs a sloka descriptive of Tansu's descendants.
>
> "Tansu was born of Saraswati by Matinara. And Tansu himself begat a son named Ilina on his wife, the princess Kalingi.
>
> "Ilina begat on his wife Rathantari five sons, of whom Dushmanta was the eldest. And Dushmanta took to wife Sakuntala, the daughter of Viswamitra. And he begat on her a son named Bharata. Here occurs two slokas about (Dushmanta's) descendants.
>
> "The mother is but the sheath of flesh in which the father begets the son. Indeed the father himself is the son. Therefore, O Dushmanta, support thy son and insult not Sakuntala. O god among men, the father himself becoming the son rescueth himself from hell. Sakuntala hath truly said that thou art the author of this child's being.
>
> "It is for this (i.e., because the king supported his child after hearing the above speech of the celestial messenger) that Sakuntala's son came to be called Bharata (the supported). And Bharata married Sunanda, the daughter of Sarvasena, the king of Kasi, and begat upon her the son named Bhumanyu. And Bhumanyu married Vijaya, the daughter of Dasarha. And he begat upon her a son Suhotra who married Suvarna, the daughter of Ikshvaku. To her was born a son named Hasti who founded this city, which has, therefore, been called Hastinapura. And Hasti married Yasodhara, the princess of Trigarta. And of her was born a son named Vikunthana who took for a wife Sudeva, the princess of Dasarha. And by her was born a son named Ajamidha. And Ajamidha had four wives named Raikeyi, Gandhari, Visala and Riksha. And he begat on them two thousand and four hundred sons. But amongst them all, Samvarana became the perpetuator of the dynasty. And Samvarana took for his wife
>
> Tapati, the daughter of Vivaswat. And of her was born Kuru, who married Subhangi, the princess of Dasarha. And he begat on her a son named Viduratha, who took to wife Supriya, the daughter of the Madhavas. And he begat upon her a son named Anaswan. And Anaswan married Amrita, the daughter of the Madhavas. And of her was born a son named Parikshit, who took for his wife Suvasa, the daughter of the Vahudas, and begat upon her a son named Bhimasena. And Bhimasena married Kumari, the princess of Kekaya and begat upon her Pratisravas whose son was Pratipa. And Pratipa married Sunanda, the daughter of Sivi, and begat upon her three sons, viz., Devapi, Santanu and Valhika. And Devapi, while still a boy, entered the woods as a hermit. And Santanu became king. Here occurs a sloka in respect of Santanu.
>
> "Those old men that were touched by this monarch not only felt an indescribable sensation of pleasure but also became restored to youth. Therefore, this monarch was called Santanu.
>
> "And Santanu married Ganga, who bore him a son Devavrata who was afterwards called Bhishma. And Bhishma, moved by the desire of doing good to his father, got him married to Satyavati who was also called Gandhakali. And in her maidenhood she had a son by Parasara, named Dwaipayana. And upon her Santanu begat two other sons named Chitrangada and Vichitravirya. And before they attained to majority, Chitrangada had been slain by the Gandharvas. But Vichitravirya became king, and married the two daughters of the king of Kasi, named Amvika and Amvalika. But Vichitravirya died childless. Then Satyavati began to think as to how the dynasty of Dushmanta might be perpetuated. Then she recollected the Rishi Dwaipayana. The latter coming before her, asked, 'What are thy commands?' 'She said, 'Thy brother Vichitravirya hath gone to heaven childless. Beget virtuous children for him.' Dwaipayana, consenting to this, begat three children, viz., Dhritarashtra, Pandu, and Vidura. King Dhritarashtra had a hundred sons by his wife, Gandhari in consequence of the boon granted by Dwaipayana. And amongst those hundred sons of Dhritarashtra, four became celebrated. They are Duryodhana, Duhsasana, Vikarna, and Chitrasena. And Pandu had two jewels of wives, viz., Kunti, also called Pritha, and Madri. One day Pandu, while out a-hunting, saw a deer covering its mate. That was really a Rishi in the form of a deer. Seeing the deer in that attitude, he killed it with his arrows, before its desire was gratified. Pierced with the king's arrow, the deer quickly changed its form and became a Rishi, and said unto Pandu, 'O Pandu, thou art virtuous and acquainted also with the pleasure derived from the gratification of one's desire. My desire unsatisfied, thou hast slain me! Therefore, thou also, when so engaged and before thou art gratified, shalt die!' Pandu, hearing this curse, became pale, and from that time would not go in unto his wives. And he told them these words, 'Through my own fault, I have been cursed! But I have heard that for
>
> the childless there are no regions hereafter.' Therefore, he solicited Kunti to have offspring raised for him. And Kunti said, 'Let it be', So she raised up offspring. By Dharma she had Yudhishthira; by Maruta, Bhima: and by Sakra, Arjuna. And Pandu, well-pleased with her, said, 'This thy co-wife is also childless. Therefore, cause her also to bear children.' Kunti saying, 'So be it,' imparted unto Madri the mantra of invocation. And on Madri were raised by the twin Aswins, the twins Nakula and Sahadeva. And (one day) Pandu, beholding Madri decked with ornaments, had his desire kindled. And, as soon as he touched her, he died. Madri ascended the funeral pyre with her lord. And she said unto Kunti, 'Let these twins of mine be brought up by thee with affection.' After some time those five Pandavas were taken by the ascetics of the woods to Hastinapura and there introduced to Bhishma and Vidura. And after introducing them, the ascetics disappeared in the very sight of all. And after the conclusion of the speech of those ascetics, flowers were showered down upon the spot, and the celestial drums also were beaten in the skies. The Pandavas were then taken (by Bhishma). They then represented the death of their father and performed his last honours duly. And as they were brought up there, Duryodhana became exceedingly jealous of them. And the sinful Duryodhana acting like Rakshasa tried various means to drive them away. But what must be can never be frustrated. So all Duryodhana's efforts proved futile. Then Dhritarashtra sent them, by an act of deception to Varanavata, and they went there willingly. There an endeavour was made to burn them to death; but it proved abortive owing to the warning counsels of Vidura. After that the Pandavas slew Hidimva, and then they went to a town called Ekachakra. There also they slew a Rakshasa of the name of Vaka and then went to Panchala. And there obtaining Draupadi for a wife they returned to Hastinapura. And there they dwelt for some time in peace and begat children. And Yudhishthira begat Prativindhya; Bhima, Sutasoma; Arjuna, Srutakriti; Nakula, Satanika; and Sahadeva, Srutakarman. Besides these, Yudhishthira, having obtained for his wife Devika, the daughter of Govasana of the Saivya tribe, in a self-choice ceremony, begat upon her a son named Yaudheya. And Bhima also obtaining for a wife Valandhara, the daughter of the king of Kasi, offered his own prowess as dower and begat upon her a son named Sarvaga. And Arjuna also, repairing to Dwaravati, brought away by force Subhadra. the sweet-speeched sister of Vasudeva, and returned in happiness to Hastinapura. And he begat upon her a son named Abhimanyu endued with all accomplishments and dear to Vasudeva himself. And Nakula obtaining for his wife Karenumati, the princess of Chedi, begat upon her a son named Niramitra. And Sahadeva also married Vijaya, the daughter of Dyutimat, the king of Madra, obtaining her in a self-choice ceremony and begat upon her a son named Suhotra. And Bhimasena had some time before begat upon Hidimva a son named Ghatotkacha. These are the eleven sons
>
> of the Pandavas. Amongst them all, Abhimanyu was the perpetuator of the family. He married Uttara, the daughter of Virata, who brought forth a dead child whom Kunti took up on her lap at the command of Vasudeva who said, 'I will revive this child of six months.' And though born before time, having been burnt by the fire of (Aswatthaman's weapon) and, therefore, deprived of strength and energy he was revived by Vasudeva and endued with strength, energy and prowess. And after reviving him, Vasudeva said, 'Because this child hath been born in an extinct race, therefore, he shall be called Parikshit'. And Parikshit married Madravati, thy mother, O king, and thou art born to her, O Janamejaya! Thou hast also begotten two sons on thy wife Vapushtama, named Satanika and Sankukarna. And Satanika also hath begotten one son named Aswamedhadatta upon the princess of Videha.

The entire lineage of the Bharatas.

Answer (score 0):

YUDHISTIRA,1st wife and love was DEVIKA and their son was YAUDHEYA,BHEEMA 1st wife was a Naga princess according to KALINGYA or ORIYA and RAJASTHAN Mahabharat before marrying HIRIMBA.GHATOTKACHA was HIRIMBA son and 4th wife was BALANDHARA and son SARVAANG. ARJUNA 2nd wife was Naga princess ULUPI and son IRAVAN,3rd wife was CHITRANGADA and son was BABRUBHAHAN and 4th wife was SUBHADRA and son ABHIMANYU. NAKULA junior wife was KARENUMATI and son NIRMITRA.SAHADEVA had 7 more wives and 8 more children. VIJAYA,RADHA, DIGAMBI, NIRANJANA, TULHAJASI, SHITSRASUDA and MALA.Children were SUHOTŔA ( VIJAYA ),VRATI ( RADHA ),VISHMA, KUNTSHI, MALVI, UJAAT, MANYU and SUHASUNDER.VIJAYA was his maternal cousin and RADHA was his favourite and most beloved wife.Apart from them PANDAVAS had 6 daughters and 5 sons with DRAUPADI. PRATIVINDYA and SUTHANU was YUDHISTIRA children.SUTASOMA and SAMYUKTHANA was BHEEMA children.SRUTAKIRTI and twins PRAGATI and PRAGYA with ARJUNA. SATANIKA and PRINTHA with NAKULA and SHRUTSENA and SUMITHRA with SAHADEVA.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE. Please provide some sources for the above list in your answer either from Mahabharata or related Hindu scriptures. This is mandatory on this site. Also please go through the below link to understand How To Write Good Answers On This site ,also  visit Help center o know more - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

And Abhimanyu was born of Subhadra, the sister of Vasudeva through Arjuna, and was, therefore, the grandson of the illustrious Pandu. And unto the five Pandavas were born five sons by (their common wife) Panchali. And these princes were all very handsome and conversant with all branches of knowledge. From Yudhishthira was born Prativindhya; from Vrikodara, Sutasoma; from Arjuna, Srutakirti; from Nakula, Satanika; and from Sahadeva, Srutasena of great prowess; and Bhima, in the forest begot on Hidimba a son named Ghatotkacha.

All the children of the Pandavas perished in the war and Parikshit, the son of Abhimanyu and the grandson of Arjuna extended the almost extinct race of Bharatas.

"And he shall beget one heroic son in his line, who shall continue the almost extinct Bharata race.' "

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_characters_in_the_Mahabharata#Bhima][1]

Bhima had a son from Valandhara, a Kashi princess who was Sarvaga, only remaining son of Bhima as he did not participate in Kurukshetra war. He became the king of Kashi, his maternal kingdom and later Sarvaga's granddaughter who is Bhima's great-granddaughter marries Abhimanyu's grandson and Arjuna's great-grandson Janamejaya and they give birth to Shatanika.

Sahadeva's son Suhotra from Vijaya and Nakula's son Niramitra from Karenumati became crown princes and later kings of Madra.

Yudhisthira's son Yaudheya from Devika ruled his maternal kingdom Sivi.