# In which Yuga was Yayati born?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, yuga, chandravansh

In conversation between Yayati and Ashtaka while Yayati was falling down from heaven, Ashtaka mentions Yayati flourished in Krita age.

Can you please let me know when was Yayati born? If Yayati was born in Krita age, when did his sons Puru and Yadu take birth?

Comment: The issue is a bit more complicated than just which of the four Yugas he lived in.  You see, we're living in the 28th Mahayuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara, and the Mahabharata took place in the current Mahayuga, but the Ramayana took place in the 24th Mahayuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7189/36. So we need to first determine what Mahayuga Yayati was born in.

Comment: Thank you, i have checked your response. Is there any mentioning of which Manavantra Yayati was born?

Comment: We definitely know that Yayati was born in the Vaivasvata Manvantara.  Yayati's father was Nahusha, Nahusha's father was Ayu, and Ayu's father was Pururavas.  Now let's look at Pururavas' parents.  Pururavas' father was Budha, god of the planet Mercury and son of Chandra the moon god.  And Chandra was born along with his brothers Dattatreya and Durvasa to the sage Atri; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/1984/36 And we know that Dattatreya was born in the Vaivasvata Manvantara; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7192/36.

Comment: And Pururavas' mother was Ila, sister of Ikshvaku and daughter of Vaivasvata Manu, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/4143/36  So both of Pururavas' parents were born in the Vaivasvata Manvantara.  Sorry if I'm overloading you with information!

Comment: I am very happy to get this good information from you. Puru was son of Yayati, if i am not wrong. So definetly he belong to our previous yuga. I am just confused with Ashtaka statement, i think Yayati is his grand father. So every thing i read about Yayati happend in previous yuga. However i havet got any info on which yuga he was born.. thank you very much for your info.

Comment: Yeah, Puru and Yadu were sons of Yayati, but what makes you think that any of them were alive during the last Dwapara Yuga?  Just because Puru's descendants like the Pandavas and Kauravas were living then doesn't mean that Puru himself was alive then.  In any case, in the Ayodhya Kanda of the Ramayana, Rama refers to Yayati going to Devaloka and falling down as something that happened "in olden times": http://www.valmikiramayan.net/ayodhya/sarga21/ayodhya_21_frame.htm And Rama lived in the 24th Treta Yuga, so Yayati was long dead even by that time.

Comment: Ok, So i think, if we believe that Yayati was born before 24th Mahayuga and lived till 28th Mahayuga then there will be very less confusion. Please correct me if i am wrong. i will try to get more info on Ashtaka that should give some more info.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to believe that Yayati was alive in the 28th Mahayuga.  Rama specifically says "As sage king named Yayati in olden times left the heaven and reached back heaven again, I shall be back to the city from the forest, after fulfilling my promise." So that means that Yayati was already dead in the 24th Mahayuga.  What makes you think that Ashtaka was alive recently?