# Is manusmriti applicable on descendants of Brahma's mind born sons?

Tags: brahma, manu-smriti, manu

As we know some of Brahma's mind born sons also had progeny. So technically not all humans are descendants of Manu. Is my understanding correct? And if so,  is manusmriti applicable on them?

Comment: Visravasa, father of Ravana, was described as the mAnasaputra of Pulastya - पुलस्त्यस्य तु तेजस्वी महार्षिर्मानसः सुतः .  Actually, what did you understand by mAnasaputra? @Carmen sandiego

Comment: Manussmriti is applicable only to descendants of Manu not to the mind born sons. Those people are already were enlightened and do not need guidance from Manu.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv - Those that were not created through a typical reproduction. Out here I am referring to sages like Atri, Bhrigu etc. So is manusmriti applicable on their descendants

Comment: @Wikash_ - I am asking if applicable on their descendants

Comment: @Carmensandiego:What you had stated is known definition.  As far as I know mAnasaputra indicates that  there are a father and a son, but they are not father and a son.  The term mAnasaputra indicates that in a subtle way about a Guru and a disciple, fathers of the both are different.  A Guru accepts a disciple, who excels his Guru, to be his son-like.  Here there is no biological relationship, but a disciple is a son-like to the Guru.  He transfers all his knowledge to that disciple only.  Sri Vivekananda is mAnasaputra of Sri Ramakrishna.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv - I see your point. And will definitely someone who thinks the timelines are extravagant , too much supernatural etc. Though the natural question would be then who are the biological parents of these rishis. But then we are digressing

Comment: @Carmensandiego:The purpose of the scriptures is to convey the main theme of the EPICs.  They are not intended to convey the history of all people, who make appearance, in the EPICs.  The main theme of Ramayana and Mahabharata is DHARMA.  That was why the details of many characters are not available therein

Comment: @Carmensandiego:Many Hindus did a mistake , while writing commentaries, in interpreting many terms used in Veda/EPICs, for one reason or the other.  So we cannot and should not go by peripheral meanings of those terms.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv - possible. And yes other than Vedas there is a good amount of adulteration and interpolation in texts. But for me if someone wrote  extravagant stuff in our texts which has survived for ages then I will not reject it on face value unless I see strong counter evidence.

Comment: Here I am not talking about interpolations. I am talking about mis-interpretations.  I am not saying to reject the EPICs as a whole. We can read them, gain from them, duly interpreting in a correct way. @Carmen sandiego

Comment: I am with you. Need right interpretation, and hence my question. Brahma et all have performed so many activities which don't seem plausible in this day and age , but it would be incorrect to put all such things as misinterpretation or  allegory. We are then staring at a whole new Epic. And as we can't discaed them, I don't see why notion of mind born sons in literal sense is to be discarded - @srimannarayanakv

Comment: @Carmensandiego I already answered your question the answer is NO. Those sons were born with utmost devotion to Brahma and hence did not need guidance.

Comment: most of the cases either mother or father was from Manu's line...can u provide examples where it was different...

Comment: @YDS - I don't have examples. But mine is a technical question. Is it applicable on all humans or just descendants of Manu

Comment: but all humans are descendants of manu in Hinduism.. that's why i asked an example..bdw here is a related Q https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/4143/12304 for Nahusha who is found connected to Manu in some way...

Comment: @YDS - there like gotras like Atri , who claim to be descendants of Maharishi Atri. Now high chances at some point there must have been marriage between someone from their ancestry with descendant of Manu. My question is whether Manusmriti was applicable on them before such marriage. Meanwhile I will look for an example from scripture

Comment: @YSS - just for my understanding. Will sage durvasa qualify as a manav (technical term)because his father is Atri but mother Anasuya is descendant from Manu?

Comment: that's bdw an incarnation...however, such cases r Manav bcz earlier Manu and Daksha appointed their daughters as Putrika means they would propogate their progeny...also u should look into Manvantara fact, the mind born son in first Manvantara might hv taken rebirth by 7th manvantar like Vasishtha...