# Why did Lord Krishna not help Abhimanyu in Mahabharata?

Tags: krishna, abhimanyu

Lord Krishna was supporting the pandavas. Then why Lord Krishna not help Abhimanyu in Mahabharata?

Comment: The answer to this is very easy, Krishna in his physical form was not present at the moment , he was busy with arjun in a different battle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lord Krishna was an avatar of God Vishnu.The establishment of Dharma{Right Order},was the main task of Lord Krishna,in the Mahabharata war.Being an avatar of God,he was fair to everyone and  partial to none,during the war.Lord Krishna was there to save "Dharma" and not any warrior. in particular.

Arjuna was the agent or means of establishing Dharma,{ by way of appointing a just future king in Hastinapur} and so Lord Krishna became his charioteer.

Abhimanyu had to break  into the Chakravyuh,as ordered by Yudhishtra,as the only other Pandava who knew how to do it viz Arjuna{his father}, was far away fighting another battle.

The other Pandavas could have attacked and countered the outer rings of the Chakravyuh, and helped Abhimanyu, but, they were prevented from doing that by Jayadratha {whom Arjuna killed in the subsequent battle}, using a boon given to him by God Shiva .

If your question has more to do with, why did Abhimanyu have to die so young, then you can read a detailed answer at this link:- [Abhimanyu's death: Was he destined to die at a young age?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/abhimanyus-death-was-he-destined-to-die-at-a-young-age)
For the full story, about how Abhimanyu was killed,you may refer to this link:-http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07032.htm