# How many sons did Arjuna have?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna

How many wives and sons did Arjuna have?

I have heard about a son called Babruvahana. Who was he & where was he gone?

Was he very powerful like Arjuna?

Comment: See my answer here for a detailed family tree: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2347/36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arjuna had 4 wives- Draupadi, Subhadra, Chitrangada and Uloopi. The respective sons are: Srutakirti, Abhimanyu, Babhruvahana and Iravan.

The son you mention is most likely Babhruvahana and his maternal grandfather (whose kingdom he inherited) was the King of present day Manipur.
He was trained in the martial arts by his step mother, Uloopi, who inspired him to achieve the feats of his father.
He could be considered to be even more powerful than Arjuna as he actually kills him in battle (it's linked to a boon that the Vasus obtain from Ganga after Arjuna fatally wounds Bhishma during the war). However, Uloopi arrives after Arjuna's death and revives him with a mystical Naga gem.

Comment: `Babhruvahana`, I dont know his correct name, but it seems to be the same. Thanks for the reply. Some more info would be great.